# Android: adding own date to achartengine

Tags: android, arraylist, time-series, achartengine

This is how I try to add my own date to TimeSeries object:

```
private void fillData() {
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor c = db.selectGewichtFromKind(id);
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrdate = new ArrayList<String>();
    c.moveToFirst();

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
    do
    {
        arr.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gewicht")));
        arrdate.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gewichtsdatum")));
        System.out.println("ARRRAY LENGHT : " + arr.size());

    }while(c.moveToNext());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        time_series.add(arrdate[i], i);
    }
}
```

Now i get an

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>
```

error in this line

```
time_series.add(arrdate[i], i);
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `ArrayList<String>` and you are trying to reference it as a `String []`.
There are two possible solutions:

If it needs to be an array -
Change `ArrayList<String> arrdate = new ArrayList<String>();` to `String [] arrdate = new String [size]`

If it should be a List (Probably this one) -
Change `time_series.add(arrdate[i], i);` to `time_series.add(arrdate.get(i),i);`

One of those should fix your exception. My guess is the second one.